# Will Office 2010 PIA's work with Office 365 (2013)?

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, office-interop, office-pia

We're trying to do some simple integration with Outlook such as synchronizing Contacts, Tasks, and Calendar with our C# .NET 4.5 project.  Can we use the Office PIA's in Visual Studio 2012 to interface with Office 2010 and 2013?  If not, do you have any suggestions on how to integrate with Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after further testing it appears they do, at least for my requirements which are generic Outlook items for Tasks, Contacts, and Calendar.